# [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fbdae1a2080

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

In `tableView` I have a few objects that are showing up just fine. However when I interact with the list and scroll down (forward) the app will crash. I have never seen this before and am not aware of why this is happening. I am using a 3rd party calendar in combination with my code, I figured I should mention this but I do not see this being the main issue.

```
#import "VRGViewController.h"


@interface VRGViewController ()

@end

@implementation VRGViewController{
    NSArray *calendarTableData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  VRGCalendarView *calendar = [[VRGCalendarView alloc] init];
  calendar.delegate=self;
  calendar.center = self.view.center;
  [self.view addSubview:calendar];

  calendarTableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto",nil];

}



-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView switchedToMonth:(int)month targetHeight:(float)targetHeight animated:(BOOL)animated {
if (month==[[NSDate date] month]) {
    NSArray *dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
    [calendarView markDates:dates];
}
}

-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView dateSelected:(NSDate *)date {
NSLog(@"Selected date = %@",date);
}


#pragma mark - User Defined Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ 
return [calendarTableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Services";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [calendarTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}


@end
```

[image: Debugging with Zombies in Instruments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your datasource the following way:

```
calendarTableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict",
                                                    @"Mushroom Risotto",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from how I was calling my array.

Since I was using 3rd party code I had disable ARC. Which was causing my issue with how I was calling my array of objects. Thank you to @meda for helping provide me with the answer - after I implemented it I then realized where I was wrong

Comment: Arc can be disabled on a file by file basis, there is no need to disable it for the entire project. Further you did not mention that in the question--bad OP.

Comment: Thank you @zaph, I should of been more specific. Yes I had disabled ARC for the 3rd party code in my project through the `Build Phases` -> `Compile Source` -> selecting the files and adding `-fno-objc-arc`